# Event initialization on declaration

Tags: c#

What does the following initialization do? I don't understand the `delegate { }` part.

```
public event EventHandler Updated = delegate { };
```

Comment: It is an "anonymous" function that does nothing.

Comment: What research did you do into the `delegate` keyword, what did you find, and how did it fail to answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things are happening here, courtesy of the language constructs. Let's break it down:

First, you are creating a public event:

```
public event EventHandler Updated;
```

Then, you are initializing it to a "default handler":

```
public event EventHandler Updated = xxx;
```

Where `xxx` **should be** a handler of type `EventHandler`. Here is the signature for that guy:

```
public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

Anyone wishing to subscribe to that event should conform to that signature.

For some odd reason, which I am not privy to, the compiler allows you provide a default implementation (property initializer) that does **not** conform to the expected signature (???):

```
public event EventHandler Updated = delegate { };
```

Notice there are no parameters. This is what the signature should be (and it compiles fine):

```
public event EventHandler Updated = delegate(object sender, EventArgs e){  };
```

You would then have access to those objects within the code.

So, in essence, you have provided a default inline delegate method that will execute when you fire the `Updated` event. This delegate of course has no instructions in it (an empty block). You can test this by changing it slightly:

```
public event EventHandler Updated = delegate { Console.Writeline("It fired!"); };
```

It would be great if someone knows the rationale for allowing this type of parameterless delegate and can augment this answer.

Answer (score 1):

This creates a new [anonymous method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/anonymous-functions) with an empty body and attaches it to the event. It's a default event handler which doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

it makes the event handler execute an empty code block. Normally it would be assigned to null, but then in the firing code you need to check if the handler is null or not. Some think that this makes that code cleaner

Comment: I don't agree it makes code cleaner. Checking for null is very simple just call "?."